# Regex: Converting currency amounts (from various formats) to a valid float

Tags: regex, preg-replace, currency

I'm working on a parser for invoices and I've found various different currency formats. Rather than reimplement a specific case for each invoice I'd rather have a general pattern that works for all cases using Regex replace.

**Example input formats**

```
2.578,20
2 354,20
234
234,256.20
234,205
246 548
244'056
26'155.25

12,20
13.33
```

**Desired Output**

```
2578.20
2354.20
234
234256.20
234205
246548
244056
26155.25

12.20
13.33
```

**My progress so far**

So far I've managed to create something that almost works
`/^(\d{0,3})?[\.\ ,']?(\d{0,3})([\.,](\d{0,2}))?/` with the replace string `$1$2.$4`

But this produces the output

```
2578.20
2354.20
234.
234256.20
234205.
246548.
244056.
26155.25
.
1220.  <---- WRONG
1333.  <---- WRONG
```

I can live with having a dot at the end as this works for floatval() in PHP and probably other languages as well. But the last two cases are invalid. I know that it matches the first `(\d{0,3})` instead the `(\d{0,2})` pattern at the end. But I'm at a loss on how to fix this...

Comment: i don't really think you can do this with the same replace string the one you specified only works with cases like 0.000,00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an alternation with 2 capturing groups and [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Match any char except a digit, dot or comma, or match a dot or comma when on the right are not 2 digits at the end of the string and replace what with an empty string.

Else capture a comma and replace that with a dot.

```
([^\d.,]|[.,](?!\d{2}$))|(,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zjdLDE/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/VBV00)

For example

```
$pattern = "~([^\d.,]|[.,](?!\d{2}$))|(,)~m";
$strings = [
    "2.578,20",
    "2 354,20",
    "234",
    "234,256.20",
    "234,205",
    "246 548",
    "244'056",
    "26'155.25",
    "12,20",
    "13.33",
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
            if (isset($matches[2])) return ".";
            if (isset($matches[1])) return "";
        }, $string) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
2578.20
2354.20
234
234256.20
234205
246548
244056
26155.25
12.20
13.33
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[^\d\n](?!\d\d$)`

Explanation:

`[^\d\n]` - negatted character class - match any character other than digit or newline character

(?!...)` - negative lookahead - match, if pattern inside is NOT matched ahead of that position

`\d\d$` - match two digits and end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGWim2/1)

It removes any non-digit characters and leaves only when they appear at the end of a string together with two digits, meaning they are decimal part :)

Replace matced text with empty string.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a bit easier syntax :) How do I fix the last comma though? For example, 12,20 should be 12.20.

Comment: @MatteusMagnusson Well, you could do it in the next step, replacing comma with dot.